# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION when testing using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm pretty new to Gradle. My project is compiling file when I do a

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

But it doesn't when I try to run the tests:

```
./gradlew connectedCheck
```

I get (a couple of them):

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/facebook/AccessToken$SerializationProxyV1;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:91)
```

here is the structure of my project:

```
main app depends on:
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.0'
    compile project(':Library:mylib')

mylib depends on:
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile files('libs/facebooksdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
```

the exception is coming for each jars from mylib, after this line:

```
:Library:mylib:dexTest
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The already added error occurs when a library is referenced more than once. What I'd do is set the compile project as the first compile element in your app and delete the repeated support-library:

```
app depends on:
compile project(':Library:mylib')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.0'


lib depends on:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
compile files('libs/facebooksdk.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
```

Comment: did all of that and still getting these errors. I'm pretty sure it's related to these jars anyway :-/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error but the message behind `already added:` is slightly different. It's about duplicate `support-v4`. What I did to tackle is:

```
compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
    exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4')
}
```

Hope it show you a new direction to fix your issue.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully. Turns out you got problem with the `connectedCheck` task. Mine is when running `gradle build`. Right now, when I run `gradle connectedCheck`, I just faced the same error. I even tried with the IDE but none of them worked.

There are actually a discussion about it here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61429 too. Due to [the comment #8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61429#c8), if you move to the app folder and run above task, you may manage. Assume that the `app` folder is `app-project/app`, the libs are put in `app-projecct/libraries/my-lib-1`. Previously, I run in `app-project` and failed.

Hope it fix.